# RxJs Dynamically add events from another EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming, rxjs

I have an Observable coming from an EventEmitter which is really just a http connection, streaming events.

Occasionally I have to disconnect from the underlying stream and reconnect. I am not sure how to handle this with rxjs.

I am not sure if i can complete a source and then dynamically add other "source" to the source, or if I have to do something like i have at the very bottom.

```
var Rx = require('rx'),
    EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

  var eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  var eventEmitter2 = new EventEmitter();

  var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(eventEmitter, 'data')

  var subscription = source.subscribe(function (data) {
    console.log('data: ' + data);
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    eventEmitter.emit('data', 'foo');
  }, 500);

  // eventEmitter stop emitting data, underlying connection closed
  // now attach seconds eventemitter (new connection)

  // something like this but obvouisly doesn't work
  source
    .fromEvent(eventEmitter2, 'data')
```

Puesdo code that is more of what i am doing, I am creating a second stream connection before I close the first, so i don't "lose" any data. Here i am not sure how to stop the Observable without "losing" records due to onNext not being called due to the buffer.

```
  var streams = [], notifiers = [];

  // create initial stream
  createNewStream();

  setInterval(function() {
    if (params of stream have changed) createNewStream();
  }, $1minutes / 3);

  function createNewStream() {
    var stream = new eventEmitterStream();

    stream.once('connected', function() {
      stopOthers();

      streams.push(stream);
      createSource(stream, 'name', 'id');
    });
  }

  function stopOthers() {
    while(streams.length > 0) {
      streams.pop().stop(); // stop the old stream
    }

    while(notifiers.length > 0) {
      // if i call this, the buffer may lose records, before onNext() called
      //notifiers.pop()(Rx.Notification.createOnCompleted());
    }
  }

  function createObserver(tag) {
    return Rx.Observer.create(
      function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ', tag, x.length, x[0], x[x.length-1]);
      },
      function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ', tag, err);
      },
      function () {
        console.log('Completed', tag);
      });
  }

  function createSource(stream, event, id) {
    var source = Rx.Observable
      .fromEvent(stream, event)
      .bufferWithTimeOrCount(time, max);

    var subscription = source.subscribe(createObserver(id));
    var notifier = subscription.toNotifier();
    notifiers.push(notifier);
  }
```

Comment: Read the part about buffering and backpressure in the docs.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I have read the docs. There are many examples on general pages and on method specific ones. This is where I got the buffer methods. Is there a specific page or portion you think would've most helpful.

Answer (score 9):

First and formost, you need to make sure you can remove all listeners from your previously "dead" emitter. Otherwise you'll create a leaky application.

It seems like the only way you'll know that an EventEmitter has died is to watch frequency, unless you have an event that fires on error or completion (for disconnections). The latter is much, much more preferrable.

Regardless, **The secret sauce of Rx is making sure to wrap your data stream creation and teardown in your observable**. If wrap the creation of the emitter in your observable, as well as a means to tear it down, you'll be able to use awesome things like the `retry` operator to recreate that observable.

So if you have no way of knowing if it died, and you want to reconnect it, you can use something like this:

```
// I'll presume you have some function to get an EventEmitter that 
// is already set up
function getEmitter() {
  var emitter = new EventEmitter();
  setInterval(function(){
    emitter.emit('data', 'foo');
  }, 500)
  return emitter;
}


var emitterObservable = Observable.create(function(observer) {
  // setup the data stream
  var emitter = getEmitter();
  var handler = function(d) {
    observer.onNext(d);
  };
  emitter.on('data', handler);

  return function() {
    // tear down the data stream in your disposal function
    emitter.removeListener('on', handler);
  };
});

// Now you can do Rx magic!
emitterObservable
  // if it doesn't emit in 700ms, throw a timeout error
  .timeout(700)
  // catch all* errors and retry
  // this means the emitter will be torn down and recreated 
  // if it times out!
  .retry()
  // do something with the values
  .subscribe(function(x) { console.log(x); });
```

* NOTE: retry catches *all* errors, so you may want to add a `catch` above it to handle non-timeout errors. Up to you.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `retry`. I am trying it out now. FYI: when i run that i get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. I think it was just because nothing was being returned from the `getEmitter`

Comment: The behavior i am trying to hit with the reconnect is to "reconnect" on my turns, without "losing data". Which requires connecting first to another eventEmitter, then disconnecting the first.

Comment: Interesting, I'll need more context, what data are you losing between connections?

Comment: So the data is coming in as a constant stream, so if i disconnect i will lose data between when I disconnect and reconnect. So my "approach", what i am trying to do is connect a second connection first, then disconnect first. That way, i 'lose' nothing.